# Laravel eloquent builder, 3 tables with relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models that are: `contracts`, `centers` and `user_centers`.

The relationship between `contracts` and `centers` is 1 to N (1 center has N contracts)

And the relation between `centers` and `user_centers`, is 1 center has N `user_centers`.

I'm trying to eloquent a function that returns contracts by filtering by a `user_id` (`user_centers` table)

For that I do the following

```
    $query = Contract::query();
    $user_id = $request->query('userId');

    $query->when(request('user_id'), function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->whereHas('centers.user_centers', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
        });
    });
```

This does not work and I do not know if I have not understood the relationship or eloquent.

Thank you

Comment: well, show me your models and proper codes of controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a function on modal

```
class Contracts extends Model {
     ...
     public function centres()
     {
         $this->hasMany(Centres::class, 'centre_id', 'id');
     }
}
```

When for 1 centers with many user_centres use this function in model:

```
class Centers extends Model {
     ...
     public function user_centers()
     {
         $this->hasMany(user_centers::class, 'user_centers_id', 'id');
     }
}
```

and eloquent :

```
Contract::with('centres')->get();
```